# Representing a linear differential equation as a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The  system of equations equivalent to $x''+p(t) x'+ q(t)x = 0$ is $\frac{dX}{dt}$ = $AX$ where $X = (x_1,x_2)^T$.

I need to find the matrix $A$.

I found it to be $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-q & -p\end{bmatrix}$

The answer shows that matrix is also $\begin{bmatrix}-p & -q\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Please explain how?

Comment: Change the order of the vector from $(x, y)$ (yours) to $(y, x)$ (theirs). What do you notice when you multiply out the solution matrix with that?

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is for $x_1=x$ and $x_2=y=x'$ but for
$x_2=x$ and $x_1=y=x'$ we have the second matrix.

Comment: If I have various options for matrices in a multiple select question, how will I see what substitution do we need to take?

Comment: And also are all these matrices similar?

Comment: So that I can discard some options.